# entity framework 5 stored procedure returns int instead of result set

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a stored procedure that recieves an ID and returns a set of results.

```
alter   PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_test]
@cod_usuario NVARCHAR(50)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON



IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM IntProgramas WHERE cod_programa IN
        (   SELECT cod_programa FROM IntGrupo_programa WHERE cod_grupo IN
            (   SELECT cod_grupo FROM IntUsuarios WHERE cod_usuario = @cod_usuario
            )
        )
    )
BEGIN
    SET nocount ON

            SELECT P.cod_programa
                     ,nb_programa
                     ,descripcion  
                     ,secuencia
                     ,P.Accion
                     ,P.Controlador
                     INTO #mitabla1 
            FROM IntProgramas P
            WHERE P.cod_programa    
            IN (
                    SELECT cod_programa FROM Intgrupo_programa WHERE cod_grupo IN 
                    (
                    SELECT cod_grupo FROM Intusuarios WHERE cod_usuario=@cod_usuario
                    )
                ) 

            SET nocount ON

            SELECT GP.cod_programa
            ,P.nb_programa
            ,P.descripcion    
            INTO #mitabla2 
            FROM IntGrupo_Programa GP 
            JOIN Intprogramas  P on GP.cod_programa = P.cod_programa
            WHERE GP.cod_grupo IN (SELECT cod_grupo FROM Intusuarios WHERE cod_usuario=@cod_usuario)--'p5202')--WHERE GP.cod_grupo IN (SELECT cod_grupo FROM Intusuario_grupo WHERE cod_usuario=@cod_usuario)--'p5202')
            --SELECT @Cuantos = COUNT(*) 
            --FROM( SELECT  nb_programa, descripcion FROM IntProgramas 
            --WHERE cod_programa in (select cod_programa from #mitabla1 
            --union  select cod_programa from #mitabla2))x

            /*si existe en ambas macheo*/
            SELECT  nb_programa, descripcion, P.cod_programa 
            INTO        #mitabla3 
            FROM        IntProgramas P
            WHERE  cod_programa in (SELECT cod_programa FROM #mitabla1 
            union  SELECT cod_programa FROM #mitabla2) 

            select 
                    t.nb_programa
                  , t.descripcion
                  , t.cod_programa
                  , p.secuencia 
                  , ISNULL(et.cod_menu,0) as cod_menu
                  , ISNULL(et.desc_menu,0) as desc_menu
                  , ISNULL(et_sprog.cod_sub_menu_programa,0) AS cod_sub_menu_programa
                  , ISNULL(et_sprov.desc_sub_menu,0) AS desc_sub_menu_N2
                  , p.Accion
                  , p.Controlador
            from #mitabla3 t  
            JOIN      IntProgramas p
                ON t.cod_programa = p.cod_programa

            LEFT JOIN IntEstructura_sub_menu_programa et_sprog 
                ON t.cod_programa = et_sprog.cod_programa 

            LEFT JOIN IntEstructura_menu_Usuarios et 
                ON et_sprog.cod_menu = et.cod_menu 

            LEFT JOIN IntEstructura_sub_menu_Usuarios et_sprov 
                ON et_sprog.cod_sub_menu_programa = et_sprov.cod_sub_menu

            WHERE et_sprog.cod_programa IS NOT NULL

            order by et.cod_menu, et_sprog.cod_sub_menu_programa, p.secuencia 
            --gp.cod_grupo, 

            drop table #mitabla1 
            drop table #mitabla2
            drop table #mitabla3


END
```

entity framework generated the following when i included the stored procedure:

```
public virtual int test(string cod_usuario)
{
    var cod_usuarioParameter = cod_usuario != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("cod_usuario", cod_usuario) :
        new ObjectParameter("cod_usuario", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("p_armar_menu_portal_usuario7", cod_usuarioParameter);
}
```

a quick test with linqpad shows that the stored procedure returns a return value and a resutlt set :
[image]

I would assume that this is caused by the fact that there is an IF EXISTS clause that means that the output is dynamic. how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove/comment content of the stored procedure and add single simple SELECT statement which returns a set of constants which has completely the same types and names like fields in your real result set. Like

```
SELECT 1 cod_programa
        , 'constant' nb_programa
        , CAST ('1' AS NVARCHAR(10)) exact_type_definition
```

Then update model from DB or update result type in function import. When code is generated - bring back real code to SP. I think you're right that IF causes the problem - EF performs a test call of SP while code generation and passes some defaults as parameters. It seems that the defaults don't satisfy IF condition and SP returns nothing to EF. By the way you can see queries EF sends to server in SQL Server Profiler and then manually check if these queries return something.